# grep: search words from files in subfolders but exclude given word from total count of matches

Tags: linux, grep, file-search

I have a folder named `folder`. Under `folder` I have two subfolders `subfolder1` and `subfolder2`.

Both of these subfolders have the same text file `file.txt`.
That text file has following lines:

```
text
text
line
line
text text
text text
```

What I am trying to do with grep is to get the total count of `text` words but exclude `text text` words from the count.

If I run `grep -ro "text" folder/ | wc -l | xargs echo "total matches :"` I get the count of 12 but the result I am looking for is 4 because those two files have only two `text` words resulting to total of 4.

I have tried to run `grep -ro "text" -v "text text" folder/ | wc -l | xargs echo "total matches :"` and many other syntaxes with -v to exclude `text text` from the count with no success.

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to achieve it using awk , In short you want to print(count) the line where "text" appears only once :

- use "text"(-F "text") as field separator
- print the lines where the number of fields are 2 when "text" is a field separator.

```
awk -F "text" 'NF==2 { print}' folder/subfolder*/*| wc -l  | xargs echo "total matches :"
total matches : 4
```

Comment: This worked great. As I am new to awk I do not understand what makes number of fields to be 2 when "text" is used as a field separator. Tried to look at examples of awk and for example when a dot was used to split an ip-address was pretty clear but I am wondering why the number of fields is two in this case. There is just one word "text" which is one field I quess so I don't know where the second field comes from?

Comment: we used "text" field separator / delimiter , So when that delimiter present once in the string then total number of fields will be 2 (NF), if the delimiter present twice total number of fields will be 3. Example : field1 text field2 , feild1 text field2 text field3

Comment: in our example , as there are no words before or after 'text' number of fields will be still 2 but those fields will be NULL/Empty.

Comment: Did you mean it like this (with delimeter ,).

"So when that delimiter present once in the string"

For example: `t,ext` <- number of fields would be 2 in this case (delimeter present once).
Or for example: `t,ex,t` <- number of fields would be 3 (delimeter present twice).
Is this how the number of fields is calculated so that `text` is split with delimeter ,?

I am sure this is simplier than I am thinking of but still a bit confused myself. :)

Comment: Yes , That is what i meant.

Comment: in short logic i applied for your requirement is , To print lines where "text" mentioned only once is , print the lines where Delimiter is "text" and number of fields are two (though they are empty).

Comment: Not sure If I still completely understood how this works (sorry).
Noticed that if I run the command with `NF==1` instead I get the same result of 4. Also `NF==3` gives the result of 4. `NF==4` however gives result of 0.

So is it so that the first field is null before `text` second field is `text` word itself and third field is null after word `text`. So the , delimeter can be placed before or after word `text` but not in the middle of the word `text`?
Wondering also why `NF==1` is also working if delimeter , splits it into at least two fields anyway?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223205/discussion-between-confused-genius-and-jm90).

Answer (score 1):

If you have `grep -P`, you can use negative lookarounds;

```sh
grep -Pro '(?<=text )text(?! text)' folder
```

If your example data is representative, you can replace the `-o` and the pipe to `wc -l` with `grep -c`.

If you don't have `grep -P`,

```sh
grep -r 'text' folder | grep -vc 'text.*text'
```

(thanks to @thanasisp) or maybe switch to Perl, or `sed`

```sh
find folder -type f -exec sed -n 's/text text//;/text/p' {} +
```

For what it's worth, the `-v` option of `grep` selects inverted behavior for *all* the patterns you specify. So

```sh
grep -e foo -v -e bar files...
```

is equivalent to

```sh
grep -v -e foo -e bar files...
```

i.e.

```sh
grep -Ev 'foo|bar' files...
```